# Match at whitespace with at most one newline in regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match `a   b` if between `a` and `b` is only whitespace with at most one newline.

Python example:

```py
import re

r = "a\s*b"  # ?

# should match:
print(re.match(r, "ab"))
print(re.match(r, "a   b"))
print(re.match(r, "a \n b"))

# shouldn't match:
print(re.match(r, "a\n\nb"))
print(re.match(r, "a    \n\n  b"))
```

Comment: What about whitespaces that are neither linefeeds nor spaces (e.g., tabs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude a newline from `\s` and then optional match a newline with any zero or more whitespace chars other than a newline:

```
a[^\S\n]*(?:\n[^\S\n]*)?b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MkCKpb/1).

*Details*:

- `a` - an `a` letter
- `[^\S\n]*` - zero or more whitespace chars other than newline
- `(?:\n[^\S\n]*)?` - one or zero occurrences of

  - `\n` - a newline char
  - `[^\S\n]*` - zero or more whitespace chars other than newline
- `b` - a `b` letter.

Comment: Wouldn't `a[^\S\n]*\n?[^\S\n]*b` work as well and be less complicated?

Comment: @luk2302 `a[^\S\n]*(?:\n[^\S\n]*)?b` is better since it is less catastrophic backtracking prone.

Comment: Doesn't `[^\S\n]` mean "zero or more chars other than *non*-whitespaces and newline"?

Comment: @InSync Thanks, I replaced the explanation with `zero or more whitespace chars other than newline`

Comment: @luk2302 It would perform a bit better if you could use a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) for the first part: [`a[^\S\n]*+\n?[^\S\n]*b`](https://regex101.com/r/vbGGWQ/1) but Python regex does not support those.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex:

```bash
a *(?:\n *)?b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q2ensk/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `a`: Match `a`
- `*`: Match 0 or more spaces
- `(?:\n *)?`: *Optionally* match a line break followed by 0 or more spaces
- `b`: Match `b`

<kbd>[Online Code Demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurSMFWoUg9UUFLw94qJk9BS9M@SZ2LS1mhOCO/NCdFITexJDnDiqugKDOvRKMoVQ/M1yjSUVBKTFLS1MQqoaCggFsOaAdYEm5FnnoJPlti8mLy8NmkAFIAsfD/fwA)</kbd>